# routePanelControl

Tags: yandex-maps-api

Добавляю на карту myMap.controls.get('routePanelControl'); и при загрузке фокус находиться в поле ввода и соответственно курсор с меткой выбора на карте точки. Как  сделать чтоб фокус был не на этом контроле по-умолчанию?

Answer (score 0):

```
var control = myMap.controls.get('routePanelControl');

control.options.set({
    autofocus: false
});
```

Comment: autofocus не работает. Может можно как то загнать эту форму под кнопку?

Comment: Да, можно. Вот так называется контрол "routeButtonControl" https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/doc/jsapi/2.1/ref/reference/control.RouteButton-docpage/

Comment: А что значит "autofocus не работает"? Вот тут работает? https://jsfiddle.net/xqosbdtv/